# How to keep counter adding while holding a button

Tags: app-inventor

I am trying to make a counter that will add +1 while holding down a button in MIT App Inventor.

I have tried recursion and the while loop.

The app crashes.

Comment: Welcome to stack Overflow. If you show us the code that is crashing and explain the error that you get, then people will be able to help you. With the information you have given, people will just have to guess what you did incorrectly.

Comment: Actually I am trying to figure out how to create it. And what I tried was just the wrong way. So I think it does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one thread for App Inventor apps, so the while loop will crash your app after a while... Use the clock component instead...

Some helpful links
[The model of event processing in App Inventor](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/m8i32I2m200/Am3VYo3DTIUJ) by Lyn
The '[Do something](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/HyitZbwMJOA/2hYC_Z3K1tQJ)' example